# Matlab Pre-allocate memory gives zeros all the time, how to avoid?

Tags: matlab, memory

In the beginning of a function, we have to pre-allocate memory by doing something like this: integ_signal=zeros(5,4);

Using the below code as an example, if I comment out this line: integ_signal=zeros(5,4);, I will get the desired answer which is 10.1 instead of 0.1. But, in Matlab Function block, I have to pre-allocate memory, how could I pre-allocate memory at the same time still won't assign zero to the integ_signal all the time?

```
integ_signal(1,1)=10;
integ_signal=zeros(5,4);
a=zeros(10);
arr=zeros(5,4);
count=2;
a=1;
integ_signal(count,1)=  integ_signal(count-1,1);
arr(count,1) = integ_signal(count,1); 
arr(count,1) = arr(count,1) + abs(I(1,a)-I(1,a+1));

(Desired answer, without pre-allocating memory)
>> arr
arr =

         0         0         0         0
   10.1000         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0

(Wrong answer, with pre-allocating memory)
>> arr

    arr =

     0         0         0         0
0.1000         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0

function integ_signal= fcn(I,V,count,oldval)       
integ_signal=zeros(5,1); 
a=zeros(10); arr=zeros(2,4); 
if count==1 
integ_signal(count,1) = 10; % Initial Condition end   
if count>1 
integ_signal(count,1)= integ_signal(count-1,1);
 arr(count,1) = integ_signal(count,1); 
 arr(count,1) = arr(count,1) + abs(I(1,a)-I(1,a+1)); 
end 
a=a+1;
end
```

When the count increases to 2, it needs to retrieve the value when count is 1, however, due to the pre-allocation, it always gives value zero to ALL previous values.

Comment: Is this MATLAB? Please tag the question accordingly. Putting the programming language first helps organize questions.

Comment: Yep, looks like MatLab

Comment: sorry, yes Matlab. I should have mentioned it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgive me if I misunderstand your question, but you are "preallocating" *after* you assign the value of `10` that you wanted.  Didn't you mean to swap those first two lines?

```
integ_signal = zeros(5,4);
integ_signal(1,1) = 10;
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. Actually it is a loop. When the count increases to 2, it needs to retrieve the value when count is one, however, due to the pre-allocation, it always gives value zero to ALL previous value. 
    function integ_signal= fcn(I,V,count,oldval)
    integ_signal=zeros(5,1);
     a=zeros(10);
     arr=zeros(2,4);
     if count==1
     integ_signal(count,1) = 10; % Initial Condition
    end
     if count>1
        integ_signal(count,1)=  integ_signal(count-1,1);
      arr(count,1) = integ_signal(count,1);
      arr(count,1) = arr(count,1) + abs(I(1,a)-I(1,a+1)); end
      a=a+1;end

Comment: So, do your preallocation/zeroing before the loop if you want the loop to continually modify the data in the matrix.

Comment: I have updated the complete code in a more organized way in the above post, please. I could not add it here due to space limitation

Comment: Yes I preallocate before the loop